# onBeforeSendHeaders does not work with Chrome desktop shortcut

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

A simple Chrome extension that enables [Youtube TV](https://www.youtube.com/tv#/) on my Raspberry Pi 4: [Source](https://github.com/angeloanan/youtube-tv-browser/tree/master/src/chrome)

**background.js**

```
const config = {
  userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (SMART-TV; Linux; Tizen 5.0) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 NativeTVAds Safari/538.1'
}

function changeUserAgent (request) {
  for (let header of request.requestHeaders) {
    if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "user-agent") header.value = config.userAgent
  }

  return { requestHeaders: request.requestHeaders }
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(changeUserAgent, {urls: ["*://*.youtube.com/tv*"]}, ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

**manifest**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "YouTube TV for Browser",
  "description": "Enables YouTube TV for traditional browser",
  "version": "0.1",

  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://*.youtube.com/tv*"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "YouTube TV for Browser"
  }
}
```

However, when I create a desktop shortcut and open Youtube from it (**with no other Chrome process running**), the script doesn't load (which will redirect me to normal youtube.com) until I manually refresh the page.

My question is: How can I load the script before Chrome send a request, or right after the shortcut opened.

Comment: Chrome starts the active tab earlier than extension's background script so this won't work. You can use [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by not solving it. Modify `--user-agent` in shortcut properties instead, [detail here](https://youtu.be/0SwiSxuE0Sg?t=100).

```
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.77 Large Screen Safari/534.24 GoogleTV/092754 Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.77 Large Screen Safari/534.24 GoogleTV/092754"
```